# How to do substitution in Bash

Tags: bash

Well for example:

```
i="Hello Bash"
j=i
```

I want to use $j to replace i like

```
echo $$j
```

So it prints "Hello Bash".
Of course it doesn't work, but I hope you understand what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable indirection:

```
i='Hello Bash'
j=i
echo ${!j}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method of doing this is:

```
i="Hello Bash"
j=i
eval echo \$$j
```

If for some reason you have a user-set variable, you can use it to call another function or something.